# Angular how to edit all elements in an array at ones

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

i currently have an array of objects i use to generate html checkboxes (ng-repeat). All those objects have an x.checked = true / false attribute. How can i set this x.checked = false for all objects at once?

Right now i use a simple for loop.

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i].checked = false;
}
```

Does Angular have a faster or shorter way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)

Comment: May be you need to use `ng-init` or loop I guess. http://plnkr.co/edit/JQnCnmSEAqyj93Sgs9KJ?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do it per se, no matter how you write it, you will never do it all at once, it will at best be a shorthand for what your wrote above.

Comment: They go through the entire list, it's `O(n)` complexity

Answer (score 1):

Yes , You can use `angular.forEach` for this, Like so:

```
angular.forEach(array, function (item) {item.checked = false;}
```

Comment: It's also loop right? But I don't know which is faster, `angular.forEach` or `for`

Comment: yes, it is also loop. angular.forEach is slower than for.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) similar syntax to angular.forEach but I think it will be faster.

```
items.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
  item.checked = false;
});
```